# Add elements to associative array in foreach loop

Tags: php, json, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm creating my own API for an Android app but I cant seem to be able to solve this. (Note this is my first php project).

What I am trying to achieve is to add an element to an associative array and then encode it to JSON but instead the only thing I have achieved is to encode the JSON each time the loop repeats resulting in a bad formatted JSON.

This is the function with the loop

```
function checkLike($media_id, $user1_id, $access_token){

    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$media_id.'/likes?access_token='.$access_token;

    $json1 = file_get_contents($url);

    $arr1 = json_decode($json1);

    $arr = array('media_id' => $media_id, 'hasLiked' => 0);


    if(is_array($arr1->data)){      
        foreach ($arr1->data as $key => $value) {
            //echo 'Comprobando el id '.$value->id.' deberia ser '. $user1_id.' ';

            if($value->id === $user1_id){
                $arr = array('media_id' => $media_id, 'hasLiked' => 1);
            }else{
                echo 'nope';
            }

        }encode_json($arr);
    }else{
        echo 'false1';
    }

}
```

and this is the other loop it's being called from

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$token.'&count=5');

$arr = json_decode($json);



if (is_array($arr->data)) {
    foreach ($arr->data as $key => $value) {
        checkLike($value->id, get_user_id($user, $token), $token);
    }
}
```

However, the JSON I get is the following:

```
{"media_id":"1198059901794013237_483636171","hasLiked":0}
{"media_id":"1196611512178987610_483636171","hasLiked":1}
{"media_id":"1195162888588906891_483636171","hasLiked":1}
{"media_id":"1193726158308528216_483636171","hasLiked":1}
{"media_id":"1192260158916546943_483636171","hasLiked":1}
```

What do I have to do to get something like this?

```
{
   "photos":[
      {
         "mediaID":"1198059901794013237_483636171",
         "hasLiked":0
         }, {
         "mediaID":"1196611512178987610_483636171",
         "hasLiked":1
         }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `$arr = array("photos"=>array('media_id' = $media_id, 'hasLiked' => 1));`

Comment: Or outside the loop.. `encode_json(array("photos"=>$arr));`

Comment: I think encode_json is typo here

Comment: @devpro Hey, thanks for answering, but as there are 2 loops and the first one is a function, I cant call the encode_json (my own function that only does echo(json_encode($foo) , its not a typo haha) on $arr as it is a variable declared inside the function. I dont know if I'm explaining properly.

Comment: U use where u need photos index

Comment: still searching for answer? if not than chose the best answer and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your array with every loop. In your loop change this line as follows:

```
$arr[] = array('media_id' => $media_id, 'hasLiked' => 1);
```

`$arr` will then be an array of arrays and when when you call `json_encode($arr)` outside of the loop, you'll get all the data in one JSON string.

Here is the fully fixed code - this should work, but I haven't tried it:

```
function checkLike($media_id, $user1_id, $access_token){

    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$media_id.'/likes?access_token='.$access_token;

    $json1 = file_get_contents($url);

    $arr1 = json_decode($json1);

    // Initialize and add first element to array
    $arrJSON[] = array('media_id' => $media_id, 'hasLiked' => 0);

    if(is_array($arr1->data)){ 

        foreach ($arr1->data as $key => $value) {           

            if($value->id === $user1_id){

                // Add to $arrJSON
                $arrJSON[] = array('media_id' => $media_id, 'hasLiked' => 1);

            }else{

                echo 'nope';

            }
        }

    } else {

        echo 'false1';

    }

    // Encode entire array as JSON and echo
    echo json_encode($arrJSON);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that but this is the output: `[[{"media_id":"1198059901794013237_483636171","hasLiked":0}]] [[{"media_id":"1196611512178987610_483636171","hasLiked":0},{"media_id":"1196611512178987610_483636171","hasLiked":1}]] [[{"media_id":"1195162888588906891_483636171","hasLiked":0},{"media_id":"1195162888588906891_483636171","hasLiked":1}]] [[{"media_id":"1193726158308528216_483636171","hasLiked":0},{"media_id":"1193726158308528216_483636171","hasLiked":1}]] [[{"media_id":"1192260158916546943_483636171","hasLiked":0},{"media_id":"1192260158916546943_483636171","hasLiked":1}]]`

Comment: It's creating a second entry instead of modifying the first one in case it has been liked.

Comment: are you calling the function more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line:

```
json_encode($arr);
```

With:

```
json_encode(array("photos"=>$arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was trying to create the array inside the function but I should have done it after the function was called. I used the function to return wether the user has liked a photo as a boolean. The code is:

The checkLike function

```
function checkLike($media_id, $user1_id, $access_token){

    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$media_id.'/likes?access_token='.$access_token;

    $json1 = file_get_contents($url);

    $arr1 = json_decode($json1);

    $hasLiked = false;

    if(is_array($arr1->data)){      
        foreach ($arr1->data as $key => $value) {
            //echo 'Comprobando el id '.$value->id.' deberia ser '. $user1_id.' ';

            if($value->id === $user1_id){
                $hasLiked = true;
            }else{
                echo 'nope';
            }

        }
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }

    return $hasLiked;

}
```

The main code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$token.'&count=5');

$media_array= json_decode($json);

if (is_array($media_array->data)) {
    foreach ($media_array->data as $key => $value) {
        $mediaID = $value->id;
        if(checkLike($mediaID, get_user_id($user, $token), $token)){
            $arrJSON[] = array('media_id' => $mediaID, 'hasLiked' => 1);
        }else{
            $arrJSON[] = array('media_id' => $mediaID, 'hasLiked' => 0);
        }
    }

    encode_json(array('photos'=>$arrJSON));
}
```